# Rectangular 2D character arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I'm using the 2D character arrays for storing multiple strings. The code below **works fine** & outputs the proper strings.

```
    char str[3][4];

    std::cin >> str[0] >> str[1] >> str[2] >> str[3];

    std::cout << str[0] << '\n' << str[1] << '\n' << str[2] << '\n' << str[3];
```

**but** when I try this

```
    char str[3][3];

    std::cin >> str[0] >> str[1] >> str[2];

    std::cout << str[0] << '\n' << str[1] << '\n' << str[2];
```

Then, if I input

`abc`

`xyz`

`pqr`

I get the output

`abcxyzpqr`

`xyzpqr`

`pqr`

What might be the possible explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're allocating 3 `char`s per string and they are of length 3 - so there's no `\0` at the end of the string. C++ strings should end with a `\0` to mark the end. When 4 `char`s are allocated, C++ automatically pads each string with a `\0`. It's safe to create arrays of at least `n+1` `char`s when you need to store at most `n` `char`s in that.

It seems that the total 9 `char`s of `str` are contiguous, so the first string is of length 9. The `cout` statement goes to print from `str[0][0]`, and as there's no `\0` at the end of `str[0]`, it continues printing `str[1]` and `str[2]`.

Answer (score 4):

The size of your strings is `3` and you are giving 3 characters in input. Which means that it doesn't get the space to store the null character `\0` and therefore can't find the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that C strings are null-terminated. This means that they are treated as ending when the first occurrence of a null character ('\0', value 0) is encountered.

When you enter the three-character string "abc" into str[0], this will be represented in memory as {'a','b','c','\0'}. Four characters, the last being the null-terminator.

This null terminator is then overwritten by the following input as str[0] is a 3-char string and thus, the null terminator will be written to str[0][3] which is equivalent to str[1][0].

Answer (score 2):

These strings are named '0-terminated', because a literal string, in C, is a sequence of characters terminated by a 0 (null byte).

You are overflowing the terminator with the first character of the successive string.

Beware to undefined behaviour.